# Error while installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle and friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.adcisolutions.com/knowledge/getting-started-rest-api-symfony-4). Problem for me occured when i was trying to install friends of symfony user-bundle and/or oauth-server-bundle via composer.

Only thing I found out googling was someone asking same question 12 days ago https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/issues/638

[image]

Comment: For most intents and purposes the FOS bundles have been abandoned.  Very sad.  Just read through the github issues.  Find yourself another OAuth server before you get sucked into quicksand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend FOSUserBundle. Nowaydays it's not really necessary anymore as Symfony's security component together with the docs or the MakerBundle delivers most of what you need the bundle for.

If you insist on using it, try setting up the bundle configuration in your `config.yml` and then try `composer require` again. In your case the problem is the missing configuration for the bundle, see [Step 5: Configure the FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#step-5-configure-the-fosuserbundle) in the docs.

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

As you can see the missing first section `db_driver` is exactly what your error message complains about.